# edittext inside tablerow android

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, tablerow

i have a textview and an edittext inside a tablerow..
my problem is when i try to write many chars in edittext then i cant see what i am writing..it seems like problem in width..Any way to make multiline row or scolling edittext while i am writting?

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="30dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/banner" >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18dip" 
            android:text="Username"
             />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entry1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/password_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18dip" 
            android:text="Password" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entry2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:password="true" />
    </TableRow>     
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to scroll inside of edittext,,,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `android:lines`/`android:maxLines`?

Comment: if  i set android:lines="2" in the edittext then i have 2 lines edittext from start...
if i set android:maxLines in the edittext then nothing happens..

Comment: What about android:inputType="textMultiLine" ?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this its help For You.**

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/table" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/banner">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/username_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff" android:textSize="18dip" android:text="Username" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/entry1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/password_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff" android:textSize="18dip" android:text="Password" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/entry2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:password="true" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```